# Node.js Server Closing Randomly

Tags: node.js

I've tried having a google but can't seem to come up with any answers. I start my node.js server using the command:

```
node server.js
```

However, after maybe an hour live the connection seems to have closed. I don't know if this is because it's idle and no one is using it. However, I'm interested to know is there a setting somewhere that I need to set for it not to close.

Comment: is the script still running?

Comment: I haven't closed it manually, but when I try to visit the page after an hour or so it says it can't connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set up some logging first, to find out why your app is crashing
see [Where is nodejs log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815218/where-is-nodejs-log-file)

If you want to restart it automatically after crashes, forever is a good option https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever