# How to access (node.js) server logs and show in front end in angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am using angular framework to build a small app and i am trying to bring the server logs to the front end (show in html page). please let me know the best way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: What I do is export logs as JSON, and then use node.js to serve the static files for the log page - you can use whatever suits you for serving the static files

Comment: so where can i find the logs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10815271/2938008 i think you should look here, nodejs doesn't have default log

Comment: can you suggest me some examples how to export the server logs as json. Thanks

Comment: I've followed this article from nodejs blog http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/03/28/service-logging-in-json-with-bunyan/

Comment: I exported the json data into a fille. how can i display those logs to the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to gather my comments into a answer:

What I do is export logs as JSON, and then use node.js to serve the static files for the log page - you can use whatever suits you for serving the static files
stackoverflow.com/a/10815271/2938008 i think you should look here, nodejs doesn't have default log

now to show logs on frontend you need to serve the log files (make them accessible) from backend using apache, nginx, nodejs - whatever really suits you best. Then using angular make a request i.e.

```
$http.get('mylogs.json').success(function(data){
  processLogs(data)
})
```