# Nodejs server suddenly shutdown

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm experiencing a problem with forever and a little node server.

The server is used as API rest to control gpio port for a raspberry pi. I start the server with `forever gateServer.js &` to start processing in background. I can see the process in execution with `ps -aux | grep node`. After that I log off.

Some time later the app cannot contact the server and in fact it is no more working. Where can I look for errors?

There is something wrong in what I do?

Comment: May be your computers memory running out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [Where is nodejs log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815218/where-is-nodejs-log-file). Try running your server with regular node process, and if it works the same way, it should error out and log out to your logfiles.

If that doesn't work, I'd say your server may shut off or just become inactive because of some underlying hardware issue. If you are running linux, for example, and you call `logout`, it will terminate all that user's processes, even if called with `forever`.

Comment: I'm so stupid :-( After start server I logoff so as you told the server shutdown... How can I start a server with forever and logoff?

Comment: You can't really "logoff"; you would have to keep the user logged in and just exit your SSH client (using the `exit` ssh command), or if you're manually connecting to the server, just leave it as it is. You could also run as `root`, but that's not ideal for production servers.

Comment: Hmm... I can't understand... You say that node js require a session always active? It doesn't seem to be secure or not?

Comment: That's definitely secure, since the user running the session can't modify root server settings (unless you tell it to), and can quickly be shut down in case of an attack. It's more secure than letting it run lower level and in the background of the entire system because the entire system is more vulnerable than a single user.

Comment: Try running your node.js server as Windows Service using node-windows.