# AWS EC2 address port not working all of the sudden. Node server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm not sure what's going on. I can SSH into my EC2 instance and start the node server. It starts with a console log of "started on port: 3000". Great. But when I try to connect to it from my website I keep receiving an error:

```
GET http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MVhTWi5 net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

Is this a problem with socket io file not being found?

Note that I was not having any problems for a month. Now all of the sudden I check my website out and boom this error. Any suggestions?

Error is being logged from the browser.

EDIT:

For some reason on one computer at my job I'm having the problem. When I go home to test it out on my other computer. No problems, the website works as intended

Comment: Have you checked logs from the node server?

Comment: honestly, I don't know how to do that. But i'll look right now to where they are

Comment: I don't think I have logs for it. It's an EC2 server not specifically setup for node. Mistake?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815218/where-is-nodejs-log-file try out some of the options from the first two answers here and you can get some logs

Comment: Did this, and nothing is being logged unfortunately

Comment: What is logging that error? Is it from the browser, or do you have a separate server running the website? If you website is on a separate server, where is that running? Is it on a corporate network, a hosting provider, AWS, somewhere else? Are you able to log into that host and connect via SSH to your EC2 instance?

Comment: The error is coming from the browser. Website is hosted on AWS. I can SSH into the EC2. I have php files that are hosted on the same EC2 that I can reach and use for http requests on my website.

Comment: This is pretty depressing lol

Comment: If you're depressed because people aren't able to give you an easy answer from a one-line error message without context, don't be. You need to do some more debugging. I would start with using your browser's "developer tools" to look at the actual network requests.

Comment: An "address unreachable" error generally indicates that you're trying to connect to an invalid IP address, such as a private IP from the public Internet. But that shouldn't happen if you're using a resolvable hostname. So maybe you have a hardcoded IP somewhere, or maybe your client-side library is incorrectly reporting a timeout or connection refused as address unreachable.

Comment: It was a joke. 

For some reason on one computer at my job I'm having the problem. When I go home to test it out on my other computer. No problems, the website works as intended.